# Sublime add text per 5000 lines

Tags: sublimetext3, text-parsing

I have large .sql file with (multiple inserts).

I want using sublime 3 to add per 5000 lines , one command like :

```
commit;
```

Is it possible ?
Thanks ijn advance

Comment: [Ctrl]+[G], for Goto. Enter you line number. Press [Ctrl] + [V]. Or you can take 5 minutes and do it any programation language. The pseudo code should look like: `var lines = ReadAllLines(FilePath); var nbLines = lines.Count(); var nbSplit= nbLines/ 5000; For i in Range(1, nbSplit).Reverse(){Lines.Insert("MyText");}; WriteFile(newPath, lines);`

Comment: I don't know if it will be that easy doing a SublimeText Snippet for that but in any programming language it's about 10 lines of code with no validation or error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex you can capture a line using : `(.+\s)` .
Then add a quatifier to determine the number of lines you want to capture: `{5000}`
And replace the Group of N lines by : "[Group of N lines][My new Text][newLine]"
It give you : `$0newData\n

Here is an exemple on a simple text file, with "newData" every 3 lines. And [an online exemple](https://regex101.com/r/ZkPgsD/1).   [image]

Nb: Click the **<kbd>.*</kbd>**, to activate the "Use regex in find search" option.

Comment: Thank you but I get 
"Ran out of stack space trying to match the regular expression"

Comment: @Prokopis, Does [Replace] work better? it should try to match in only one at a time. Still sublime text is not build for those kind of operation: parsing gigabyte of data per 5000 lines bundles. script would be easier to write. You should press Replace the N times where n is the result of the integer division of number_Lines / batch_Size

Comment: An other simple solution is to create a simple script "autoit"/"ahk" press Arrow down 5000time, ctrl+V. run this for few second clear the end of the file from exccesive copy-paste.

Comment: So we have: simple script, Regex from PowerShell, Regex in sublime text, a macro in sublime text. a macro in a macro language ahk etc. And so many others heteroclite solution. It's starting to looks like a code golf.  For a simple 20lines text It can be done a TI-89.

Comment: updated the regex to remove one capture group perhaps ot will help. `(.+\s)`  instead of `((.+)\s)`